# More efficient way to solve a Ruby exercise asking for the return of 2 indices, without using nested loop?

Tags: ruby

Sorry if the title was not clear. I have a problem that is solved, but I was hoping for insight into how to solve without using nested loop or if there was a more efficient method. Thanks!

```html
# Write a method that takes an array of numbers. If a pair of numbers
# in the array sums to zero, return the positions of those two numbers.
# If no pair of numbers sums to zero, return `nil`.

def two_sum(nums)
  nums.each_with_index do |num, i1|
    for i2 in i1 + 1...nums.length
      return [i1, i2] if num + nums[i2] == 0
    end
  end

  nil
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts(
  'two_sum([1, 3, 5, -3]) == [1, 3]: ' + (two_sum([1, 3, 5, -3]) == [1, 3]).to_s
)
puts(
  'two_sum([1, 3, 5]) == nil: ' + two_sum([1, 3, 5]).nil?.to_s
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two items in array with Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905245/comparing-two-items-in-array-with-ruby)

Comment: No. That is just a comparison of elements. This requires the return of their indices.

Comment: By more efficient, do you mean better time complexity than `O(n^2)`, or just cleaner looking code?  Both are valid pursuits, but one most likely wont look the same as the other.

Comment: On the Ruby farm, `for` loops bad...

Comment: `two_sum([1,2,3,0]) #=> [3,3]`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! (changed the for loop to <% i + 1 %> to avoid the comparison of same element.)

Comment: @DavidSawatske Why would you delete the question about primes and slippery numbers, **after** I wrote an answer with the required info and an optimized version of your method?

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following.

```
def two_sum(nums)
  nums.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(n, idx),h|
    return [h[-n], idx] if h.key?(-n)
    h[n] = idx
  end
  nil
end

two_sum [1,2,4,5,-2,6]
  #=> [1, 4]
two_sum [1,2,4,5,-3,6]
  #=> nil
two_sum [1,-2,5,-2,6,2]
  #=> [3, 5]
```

If I were to change `h[n] = idx` to `h[n] = idx unless h.key?(n)` the last example above would return `[1, 5]`.

For readers unfamiliar with [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), the code above is equivalent to the following

```
def two_sum(nums)
  h = {}
  nums.each_with_index do |n, idx|
    return [h[-n], idx] if h.key?(-n)
    h[n] = idx
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: Nice variation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this answer as base to start:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905895/2552259

And then adapt the answer to your requirements:

```
def get_two_indexes(ary)
  aryx = Hash[(0...ary.size).zip ary]  
  couples = aryx.to_a.combination(2).to_a
  matches = couples.map {|pair| pair.map{|x| x[1]}.inject(:+).zero?}
  indexes = matches.map.with_index {|match,index| 
    match ? couples[index].map{|x| x[0]} : nil
  }.compact
  indexes.empty? ? nil : indexes
end

irb > [[1,-1], [0,0], [1,-1,1,-1],[1,2]].map{|ary| get_two_indexes(ary)}
=> [[[0, 1]], [[0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3]], nil]
```

This will return the indexes of the matching combinators that sums zero, nil if no value matches, and proper indexes if there are repeated values in the array.

Comment: Defined ary and now returns an array of indexes matching.

Comment: There is a problem when the array contains two zeroes and no other pairs that sum to zero: `index` will return the index of the first zero twice. Consider using `rindex` to find the index of the second element of the pair,

Comment: I ignored the repeated values in arrays, `[0,0]`, or `[-1, 1, -1, 1]` will retrieve the index of the first ocurrence. Also the question states some other conditions, like: it will return true at the end, and nil should return if none matches. Improving my answer right now.

Comment: Another way of using `combination`: `ary.each_index.combination(2).find { |i,j| ary[i] == -ary[j] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland pretty cool, but missing a `to_a` after `each_index`:)

Comment: @sagarpandya82, ah, yes, always test! Thanks, pandy. `ary.each_index.to_a.combination(2).find { |i,j| ary[i] == -ary[j] }`.